# Как изменить цвет с синих на какой то другой и как выделить пространство?

Tags: html, css, color

Как я могу убрать синий цвет (он не меняется в css, я пробовал). И можно ли как то сделать так чтобы слова present simple и past simple и т.д. не были так близко друг к другу.

```css
@Charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  width: auto/9;
}

.left {
  float: left
}

;

/* в img максимально 100% изоброжение будет подстраиватся под блок и не вылезать из него и auto/9 это для эксплоера браузера*/

header,
footer {
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}

aside {
  width: 270px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-top: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* стили для футера*/

footer {
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}

.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer,
.content:after {
  height: 10px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 77%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/english1.jpg" alt="LearningEnglish" title="LearningEnglish" /></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <div id="menuhrefs"></div>
  <a href="presentsimple">Present simple</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastsimple">Past simple</a>
  <hr /><a href="presentcontinuous">Present continuous</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastcontinuous">Past continuous</a>
  <hr /><a href="pastperfect">Past perfect</a>
  <hr /><a href="cancould">Can, could</a>
  <hr /><a href="willwould">Will, would</a>
  <hr /><a href="reading">Reading</a>
</aside>

<div class="content"></div>
<footer>
  <span class="left">Privacy policy &copy; 2018</span>
</footer>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в `footer` последний открывающий `<span>` заменен на закрывающий `</span>`

Comment: спасибо. Но не помогло

Comment: при чем здесь *не помогло* - у Вас два открывающих `span` было в блоке.

Comment: *present simple и past simple и т.д. не были так близко друг к другу* - нужен отступ между строк или нужен отступ между словами *present* и *simple* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял чего вы хотите добиться. Но по-моему меню делают как-то так.

```css
@Charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
     width: 270px; /* Ширина слоя */
     height: 2.2em; /* Высота слоя */
     line-height: 2.2em; /* Выравнивание по вертикали */
     background: #ddd; /* Цвет фона */
    }
.link:hover {
     background: #aaa; /* Цвет фона при наведении */
    }
.link a {
     display: block; /* Ссылка как блочный элемент */
     text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
     height: 100%; /* Высота на весь слой */
     color: #666; /* Цвет ссылки */
    }

img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  width: auto/9;
}

.left {
  float: left
}

;

/* в img максимально 100% изоброжение будет подстраиватся под блок и не вылезать из него и auto/9 это для эксплоера браузера*/

header,
footer {
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}

aside {
  width: 270px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-top: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  /*padding-left: 8px;*/
  /*padding-top: 12px;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* стили для футера*/

footer {
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}

.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer,
.content:after {
  height: 10px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 77%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/english1.jpg" alt="LearningEnglish" title="LearningEnglish" /></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <div id="menuhrefs"></div>
  <div class="link"><a href="presentsimple">Present simple</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="pastsimple">Past simple</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="presentcontinuous">Present continuous</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="pastcontinuous">Past continuous</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="pastperfect">Past perfect</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="cancould">Can, could</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="willwould">Will, would</a></div>
  <hr /><div class="link"><a href="reading">Reading</a></div>
</aside>

<div class="content"></div>
<footer>
  <span class="left">Privacy policy &copy; 2018</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: *Не совсем понял чего вы хотите добиться* - для уточнений есть возможность оставить комментарий под вопросом )

Comment: Мне бы хотелось бы убрать синий цвет и чтобы был черный.

Comment: В моём варианте у ссылок синий цвет? Может у вас свой стиль для ссылок в браузере включен?

Comment: Alex это риторический вопрос. Не придирайтесь к словам.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `<hr>` используйте css свойство `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc`
Ознакомиться подробнее можно [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border)